# VideoJS - custom settings for fullscreen mode?

Tags: video.js

I would like to hide the `controlBar` by default, but re-enable it on fullScreen-mode. I can hide the controlBar like this:

```
var player = videojs(videoTag[0], {
     controlBar: false
});
```

But something like

```
var player = videojs(videoTag[0], {
     controlBar: false,
     fullScreen: {
         controlBar: true
     }
});
```

doesn't seem to work.

Is it possible to do this from the settings object, or should I simply hide/show it form CSS (using `.vjs-fullscreen`)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`controlBar: false` in the player options omits the control bar altogether.

Instead, use `player.controls(false)` to disable them and `player.controls(true)` to show.

```
player.on('fullscreenchange', function(e) {
  if (player.isFullscreen()) {
    player.controls(true);
  } else {
    player.controls(false);
  }
});
```